# keyCode or detection for selection in textbox

Tags: jquery, keycode, keyup

How can I detect whether the user is selecting the text in the `<input>` box?

```
$('input[name=inputname]').keyup(function(e)
{
   if((e.keyCode!=37)&&(e.keyCode!=38)&&(e.keyCode!=39)&&(e.keyCode!=40)) // Check whether the user is navigating inside the box by pressing the arrows
   {
        call_the_function();
   }
});
```

Now when the user selects the text he/she typed by using Shift + Left Arrow or Shift + Right Arrow, the `keyUp()` function executes. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Do you not need to change the AND's "&&" to OR's "||"?

Comment: What about selection with the mouse? This is a futile problem to solve anyway, as I can copy whatever value from the source of the website if I need it that badly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I don't need to prevent copying the text. My question is when the user presses Shift key along with navigation keys, the `keyUp()` event is fired. I need to prevent that. How it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DxjT/1)

```
$('input[name=inputname]').keyup(function (e) {
    if (event.shiftKey && ((e.keyCode >= 37) && (e.keyCode <= 40)))
    {
        return false;
    }else{
        console.log('hi'); //call function when shift+arrow keys not pressed together 
    }
});
```

or

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DxjT/2)

```
$('input[name=inputname]').keyup(function (e) {
    if (!(event.shiftKey && ((e.keyCode >= 37) && (e.keyCode <= 40)))) {
        console.log('hi');  //call function when shift+arrow keys not pressed together 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('input[name=inputname]').keyup(function(e)
{
   if((e.keyCode!=16)&&(e.keyCode!=37)
       ||(e.keyCode!=16)&&(e.keyCode!=38)
       ||(e.keyCode!=16)&&(e.keyCode!=39)
       ||(e.keyCode!=16)&&(e.keyCode!=40)) // Check whether the user is navigating inside the box by pressing the arrows
   {
        call_the_function();
   }
});
```

This should check for the SHIFT Key and either the left, right, up or down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

what about using jquery select()

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/xWEPh/

```
//http://api.jquery.com/select/
$( "#target" ).select(function() {
alert( "Handler for .select() called." );
});
```

you could easily disable the keyup events for selecting with the keyboard. This has to be done in the keyup event handler.